# Adding "Explicit" Label to Songs

Tags: itunes, music, m4a

When transferring a song from a CD to my iTunes library (or downloading an `.mp3`), I've noticed that `Explicit` and `Clean` labels are not present (as seen below).

[image: Tha Carter IV]

I've already added *all* the information to every song, and now, all that I'm missing are the `Explicit` labels. Is there any, preferably programmatic, way to add these labels to songs I've imported to my library without downloading/using a third party program?

---

<sup>I've converted my imported files to AAC versions (`.m4a` format), which I imagine is more versatile for this purpose.</sup>

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45178/how-do-i-mark-songs-as-explicit-in-itunes-to-make-them-match-correctly-in-itunes?rq=1 for a possible answer

Comment: I looked around the site for a bit, looking for a similar question (found the one you linked, among others). The problem with the answers on that question is that they're over three years old, and the accepted answer is using third party software on a visibly (much) older version of iTunes. I'm looking for something that can be used via Terminal, AppleScript, etc. @patrix

Comment: From taking a quick look at the source code of Subler (see linked question) it seems that the "Explicit" information is kept in the metadata part of each audio file. AFAIK there are no tools installed as part of OS X which would allow an easy way of manipulating this. So the requirement of "no third party program" may be overly restrictive here.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how metadata is stored, but it's something I'll have to look at, for sure. I would appreciate if you would repost that comment as an answer. @patrix

Comment: Duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/45178/118495